# Topology: $O \subseteq X \times Y$ implication of $O$ being open in $X \times Y$

Tags: general-topology

> Topology: $O \subseteq X \times Y$ implication of $O$ being open in $X \times Y$

Define the topological space as: 
$(X \times Y, \mathcal{T}_{X \times Y})$

We know if $O \in \mathcal{T}_{X \times Y}$ then $O$ is open, by definition of $\mathcal{T}_{X \times Y}$

Is this an implication that goes both ways? 
What if we start off knowing $O$ is open, what can we say about it being in $\mathcal{T}_{X \times Y}$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you saying all subsets of $X\times Y$ are open?

Comment: @user722227 not neccessarily, suppose we just have an open subset $O$, what can we say about it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. "we just have an open subset $O$" - in what space?

Comment: @Math1000 $O$ is open in $X \times Y$

Comment: Then $O$ is open in $X\times Y$. What is your question?

Comment: @Math1000 can we say that $O \in \mathcal{T}_{X \times Y}$?

Comment: Assuming that $\mathcal T_{X\times Y}$ is the product topology on $X\times Y$, then yes, "$O$ is open in $X\times Y$" is the exact same statement as "$O\in\mathcal T_{X\times Y}$".

Comment: The expression "$O$ is open in $X\times Y$" implicitly tells us that $X\times Y$ is equipped with a topology. If $\tau$ denotes this topology then $$O\text{ is open in }X\times Y\iff O\in\tau$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a topological space as you did, by a tuple of $(U, \mathcal T)$, then you're 'declaring' that the sets $S\in \mathcal T$ $($which are subsets of $U)$ are open.

Of course, the family of subsets $\mathcal T$ must satisfy some properties for it to earn the status of 'a topology on $U$'; not all families of subsets will do.
However, if you state that $(U, \mathcal T)$ is a topological space, it is implied or else assumed that these properties are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Of course $O \in \tau_{X \times Y}$ is saying the same as $O$ is open in $X \times Y$ (in that product topology, of course).

We can reformulate it via the definition of the product topology, if we like, to

$$\forall (x,y) \in O: \exists U \in \mathcal{T}_X, V \in \mathcal{T}_Y: (x,y) \in U \times V \subseteq O$$

to reduce it to knowing about openness in the factor spaces $X$ and $Y$.